# Selenium script is not getting the text of an element

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to get the owner of a website through my local [whois](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHOIS) with this:

```python
link = "ebdicorp.com.br"
service = service.Service('C:\Selenium\chromedriver.exe')
service.start()
capabilities = {'chrome.binary': 'C:\Selenium\chromedriver.exe'}
driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url, capabilities)
driver.get('https://registro.br/2/whois?qr=&c');
time.sleep(5)

input_site = driver.find_element_by_id("whois")
input_site.send_keys(link)
driver.find_element_by_id("captchaBtn").click()
company = driver.find_element_by_class_name("col-md-9").text

print(company)

driver.quit()
```

The problem is: I get the element with

```python
company = driver.find_element_by_class_name("col-md-9")
```

which returns `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="eae9915a3cc3f2f4690eec4a0019982d", element="0.5670714519595477-1")>`

But there isn't any text when I try with `.text`. Where am I messing up?

Comment: Can you please share full error trace

Comment: Which text represents the `owner of a website`? Which field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 20 elements with class `col-md-9`. The first one, which you get, has no text. You can use `xpath` to locate the row you are looking for by the text and from there get the value.

For example, for the "Titular" row use

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[label='Titular:']/following-sibling::*[1]").text
```

Which will give you `Studio Crazy Suporte S/C Ltda Me`

Answer (score 1):

As per the website `https://registro.br/2/whois?qr=&c` once you search with the text **ebdicorp.com.br** to extract any of the values you can write a function which will take the `<label>` name as follows:

```python
def extract_value(myString):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[.='" + myString + "']//following::div[1]").get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

Now you can call the function `extract_value()` with any of the `<label>` texts to extract its value as follows:

```python
extract_value("Titular:")
# or
extract_value("Contato do Titular:")
# or
extract_value("Contato Administrativo:")
```